# What is the length of SNMP sysUpTime counter?

Tags: cisco, snmp

What is the length of [Cisco SNMP sysUpTime counter](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=sysUpTime)? 32 bits?

Comment: Is there some doubt that the cisco implementation would comply with the RFC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did a quick test and it looks like the data is a type 'Timeticks' which is a 32 bit integer. From the RFC:

```
The TimeTicks type represents a non-negative integer which represents
the time, modulo 2^32 (4294967296 decimal), in hundredths of a second
between two epochs.  When objects are defined which use this ASN.1
type, the description of the object identifies both of the reference
epochs.
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578#section-7.1.8

```
[user@host ~]$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c $COMMUNITY $DEVICE sysUpTime
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (1342832478) 155 days, 10:05:24.78
```

Answer (score 6):

sysUpTime is a 32-bit counter and will roll over after 496 days.

snmpEngineTime (.1.3.6.1.6.3.10.2.1.3) which returns the uptime in seconds and should not roll over for 135 years.

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c xx 10.xx.xxx.xxx .1.3.6.1.6.3.10.2.1.3
SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineTime.0 = INTEGER: 1701562 seconds

snmpwalk -v2c -c xx 10.xx.xxx.xxx sysUpTime
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (170158257) 19 days, 16:39:42.57
```

Answer (score 3):

Cisco v1 MIBs import the definition of `TimeTicks` from RFC1155-SMI. This mib is part of standard snmp utils (i.e. not included in the Cisco mib tarballs). Within RFC1155-SMI, `TimeTicks` is defined as:

```
   TimeTicks ::=
       [APPLICATION 3]
           IMPLICIT INTEGER (0..4294967295)
```